# Mathematically increase warmth of RGB color

Tags: colors, rgb

I'm looking for a way to make an RGB color 'warmer'. I initially tried increasing the R component of an RGB color to make it warmer, but that yielded unexpected results. What's the correct way to  increase the warmth of an RGB color?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Of course warmth is quantifiable. You make a color warmer by adding red. Trouble is, you can't just add red. There are formulas you need to use to add the proper amounts of red and modify the blue and green components of the RGB color accordingly, and those formulas are what I'm looking for.

Comment: I call that redness :) Should hue / saturation / brightness stay constant?

Comment: sorry: Should  saturation / brightness stay constant?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to find the solution myself. In two days, I'll try to remember to post an answer of my solution. For now, I'll just leave the solution in a comment. :) Basically, I added the RGB values of a nice diluted red to my RGB color, then averaged the result by dividing by two. That did the trick. Thanks for your interest, though.

Comment: Scratch that, after more experimentation it looks like I don't have a solution at all. :) Such is life. That said, I'm open to any further suggestions.

Comment: if you're still working on this, have you considered mapping the colour temperature (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature), adjusting it a degree or 2 and then converting it back to RGB?

Comment: @dnagirl: I am still working on this, but have in fact come up with another solution. Thanks anyhow! :)

Comment: you mind posting that solution?

Comment: @Farhan: I actually don't recall it off the top of my head any more, sorry. :( I don't think I have access to the files of that project either.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for this in the future:

```
r = r + adjustment
g = g
b = b - adjustment
```

Blue should be decreased to counter the increase in red, and vice versa. Adjustment in the range 0-20 is recommended.

Source: https://tannerhelland.com/2014/07/01/simple-algorithms-adjusting-image-temperature-tint.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using Python or not - actually I just posted another answer referencing the [colorsys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) library, so I promise I'm not selling it - but I would convert my RGB values to HSV and increase the "value" or do an if-then and check some values to see where I could increase my warmth.  Sometimes increasing saturation makes an image look cartoony, where you've basically regressed from complex colors down to primary ones.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am also trying to do the same thing.

Making a color warmer is easy to do in the HSV color space.

One way is to use the `colorsys` Python library. This library allows you to convert colors between different color spaces.

We will use HSV color spaces.

The HSV color space is a cylindrical coordinate system where the hue (H) channel represents the color, the saturation (S) channel represents the intensity of the color, and the value (V) channel represents the brightness of the color. To make colors warmer in the HSV color space, you can increase the `S` channel. The saturation value tells us how much of the respective color must be added. A 100% saturation means that complete, pure color is added, while a 0% saturation means no color is added, resulting in grayscale. The hue channel ranges from 0 to 360, with 0 being red, 120 being green, and 240 being blue. Increasing the hue channel will shift the color towards red.

```
import colorsys

r, g, b = (120, 10, 20)

hue, saturation, value = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255, g/255, b/255)
saturation += 0.1
if saturation > 1:
    saturation -= 1
warmColor = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, saturation, value)
```

The above code is a simple example of how to use the library.
Remember, warmColor will be a tuple of new r, g, and b values, and all three values will be floats. Also, the function will accept values between 0 and 1. (return the values between 0 and 1)